# Generate equally-spaced values including the right end using NumPy.arange

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to generate an array between 0 and 1 with spacing 0.1. In R, we can do

```
> seq(0, 1, 0.1)
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

In Python, since `numpy.arange` doesn't include the right end, I need to add a small amount to the `stop`.

```
np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.1)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

But that seems a little weird. Is it possible to force `numpy.arange` to include the right end? Or maybe some other functions can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be very careful using `arange` for floating point steps.
[From the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.

Instead, use `linspace`, which allows you to specify the exact number of values returned.

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

`linspace` *also* does in fact let you specify whether or not to include an endpoint (`True` by default):

```
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 11, endpoint=True)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, 11, endpoint=False)
array([0.        , 0.09090909, 0.18181818, 0.27272727, 0.36363636,
       0.45454545, 0.54545455, 0.63636364, 0.72727273, 0.81818182,
       0.90909091])
```

Answer (score 4):

No, as mentioned in the docs:

> End of interval. The interval **does not include this value**...

For the end of the interval to include the actual ending value, you must add  `step` to the `end`, there's no way around. Maybe a little cleaner:

```
step = 0.1
start = 0.
stop = 1.

np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
# array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `step` to the `stop` does not always work:

```
start = 1
stop = 2
step = 0.2

np.arange (start, stop + step, step)

# array([1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. , 2.2])
```